# Spring Boot: MySQL Duplicate key error when trying to map customers to items

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to build a small Spring Boot CRUD app with some basic e-commerce functionality (i.e. add to cart, etc.). My Basic entities are customer, cheese and roles.

In trying to map customers to cheeses, it works perfectly fine with only one user. A "customer-cheeses" table is generated with the customer accountNumber (id), along with the Cheese id. Here is a picture of the table:

[image: MySQL table]

However, when trying to add items with another account, I get an error like this:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '6' for key 'UK_pg95jxw3noahgyna6qwbl3ivd'

I am assuming that this just means I can only have one cheese id. I have tried to play around with different hibernate annotations (i.e. @ElementCollection, @manytomany, etc.), but have not been able to get this to work.

Any input would be appreciated. Also, please let me know if you need any of my services or controllers, but the actual adding and removing is working fine in my app.

**Customer**

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 25)
    private String name;

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int accountNumber;

    private BigDecimal accountFunds;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 25)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_EMAIL", referencedColumnName = "email")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private List<Role> roles;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Cheese> cheeses = new ArrayList<>();


    public Customer(String name, String password, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.accountFunds = new BigDecimal(225.00); // default value
    }

    public Customer() {}

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAccountFunds() {
        return accountFunds;
    }

    public void setAccountFunds(BigDecimal accountFunds) {
        this.accountFunds = accountFunds;
    }

    public List<Cheese> getCheeses() {
        return cheeses;
    }

    public void setCheeses(List<Cheese> cheeses) {
        this.cheeses = cheeses;
    }
}
```

**Cheese**

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMax;
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Cheese {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=20)
    private String name;


    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=20)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @DecimalMax("10000.0") @DecimalMin("0.0")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Cheese() {}

    public Cheese(String name, String description, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Comment: your table generated with this code?  I think its ur db problem. If table created with oneToMany relation then this error occured.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...so, I got it working by doing the following: I changed email to customer_id, which admittedly should not make a difference. For the cheese class, I made the many to many to be "mappedBy" cheeses.

Again, I'm not sure why this works, and the other didn't, but that seems to be the case.

**Customer**

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 25)
private String name;

@GeneratedValue
@Id
private int accountNumber;

private BigDecimal accountFunds;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2)
private String password;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 25)
@Email
private String email;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="user_roles",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_EMAIL", referencedColumnName = "email")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="id")})
private List<Role> roles;

//@ElementCollection

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="cheese_customers",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "accountNumber")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName="id")})
private List<Cheese> cheeses = new ArrayList<>();


public Customer(String name, String password, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.accountFunds = new BigDecimal(225.00);
}

public Customer() {}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public BigDecimal getAccountFunds() {
    return accountFunds;
}

public void setAccountFunds(BigDecimal accountFunds) {
    this.accountFunds = accountFunds;
}

public List<Cheese> getCheeses() {
    return cheeses;
}

public void setCheeses(List<Cheese> cheeses) {
    this.cheeses = cheeses;
}
}
```

**Cheese**

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMax;
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Cheese {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=20)
    private String name;


    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=20)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @DecimalMax("10000.0") @DecimalMin("0.0")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cheeses")
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Cheese() {}

    public Cheese(String name, String description, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you could check your scheme settings to see if that field is configured as a UNIQUE field which means you can't have > 1 = 6.